# SSRS: Not displaying fields on Dataset when using SP

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, reporting-services

I have a dataset that is connected to SP then I'm using this dataset for my Parameter. But it doesn't display a field so I'm having an error. My script is working fine when ran through SQL.

I have these parameters 
ProductDivision,
SKUSEARCH (textbox for entering keyword) ,
and SKU (the parameter connected to the dataset that has problem)

What the SP does is it filters the items displayed on SKU based on the keyword that the users entered in the parameter and from the product division parameter(Multi-select) then if the user didn't enter any keyword it will just show all items under the product division.

Here's my script:

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[SP_SKUSEARCH] (@SKUSEARCH NVARCHAR(MAX),@ProductDivision NVARCHAR(MAX))
AS
DECLARE @QUERY NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @QUERY2 NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @QUERY3 NVARCHAR(MAX)

IF LEN(@SKUSEARCH)>=1
BEGIN
SET @QUERY = ''
SET @QUERY2 = ''
SET @QUERY3 = ') AND VALID = ''Y'' AND PRODUCT_GROUP IN ('''+REPLACE(@ProductDivision,',',''',''') + ''')
ORDER BY #SKU_CODE'

SELECT @QUERY = 
'SELECT DISTINCT #SKU_CODE AS SKU FROM CI_Product_Master '

FROM DBO.FN_SPLITSTRING(@SKUSEARCH)

SELECT @QUERY2 = @QUERY2 +
'OR #SKU_CODE LIKE ''' + NAME + '''
'
FROM DBO.FN_SPLITSTRING(@SKUSEARCH)

SET @QUERY2 = STUFF(@QUERY2,1,2,'WHERE (')

SET @QUERY = @QUERY + @QUERY2 + @QUERY3

EXEC (@QUERY)
END

ELSE
BEGIN
DECLARE @SQLCOMM VARCHAR(MAX)
SET @SQLCOMM = 'SELECT DISTINCT #SKU_CODE AS SKU FROM CI_Product_Master
WHERE VALID = ''Y''
AND PRODUCT_GROUP IN ('''+REPLACE(@ProductDivision,',',''',''') + ''')
ORDER BY #SKU_CODE'
EXEC (@SQLCOMM)
END
```

I have been stuck here for a couple of days now. Hope someone could help me.

Comment: what happen if you run the sp with all empty parameters? did you double check the actual sql code executed by the sp when called by ssrs?

Comment: When I put the first IF code from SP to the dataset, the Define Query Parameters pops-up then if I put value on it, it show the Field.

Then when I run the SP with empty parameters it will still run but shows all SKUs with blank Product Division

Comment: Problem solved! I just removed the script of else from SQLCOMM. It's now a direct script instead of a string.